# Get All the associations that belongs to the federation where president_id = user_id In Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables :

Federation - Association - User

An Association belongsTo a federation.

A Federation hasMany Association

Federation has a president : president_id that refers to User Model

Association has a president : president_id that refers to User Model

What I want to get:

All the associations that belongs to the federation that have the president_id == Auth::user()->id

I tried:

```
$associations = Association::with(['federation' =>function($query){
        $query->where('federation.president_id', Auth::user()->id);
    }])->get();
```

And also:

```
    $associations = Association::with('federation')
        ->where('federation.president_id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->get();
```

But in the first case, I get all the association with the federation relationship to null, and in the second case, it doesn't know federation.president_id as it queries table 'association'

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`with()` only modifies the eager loaded relationships. In order to modify a query based on its relationships, you're looking for `whereHas()`:

```
$associations = Association::whereHas('federation', function($query) {
        $query->where('president_id', Auth::user()->id);
    }])
    ->get();
```

Comment: in my question, I simplified the query, but I need several relations in with() : with('federation', 'president','country'). How should I mix them with whereHas?

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro You continue to use them as normal. `whereHas()` is just another query modifier, like `where()`, `order()`, `select()`, etc... You can use it inline with `with()`: `Assocation::with('federation', 'president', 'country')->whereHas('federation', function($q) {...})->get();`